# start vs startNonBlocking in crawler4j

Tags: java, crawler4j

I am using `crawler4j` **lib** and their **dependencies** for crawling the page. What is the difference between

```
controller.start(BasicCrawler.class, numberOfCrawlers);
```

vs.

```
controller.startNonBlocking(BasicCrawler.class, numberOfCrawlers);
```

?

Answer (score 0):

take at look at

https://github.com/yasserg/crawler4j/blob/master/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/crawler/CrawlController.java

from the documentation the second one allows the crawler thread to continue with just after triggering the crawl request.